# "Replace" adds line-break on Sublime Text 2

Tags: replace, sublimetext2, line-breaks, sublimetext

ST2 is adding a line-break after the match when replacing (single or all) a text.

Has anyone had the same problem?

I've tried (un)checking all options, like Case, Wrap, etc.

I believe is something related to a package, but couldn't find any answer so far.

[image]

Comment: hi! in your example above, how exactly (i.e. keystrokes pressed) did you change the text in the "Replace With" box?

Comment: Ctrl + H > Clicked on the "Replace All" button. OS Windows, by the way.

Comment: are you sure that there are no hidden newlines in your "replace with" box? sublime text isn't great at displaying those characters. if you do Ctrl+A and then Del on that box, do you still get the same behaviour?

Comment: it worked o.O can't believe it was THAT simple :) thanks amp!

Comment: i'm glad! :) sublime should be better at showing that kind of thing! i'll add it as an answer in case it's useful to someone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that there are no hidden newlines in your `Replace with` box. (Sublime Text isn't great at displaying those characters.)

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to Select All and then <kbd>Delete</kbd> to delete the contents of that box. That should get of all characters, including invisible ones.